# Composing Futures of a required and optional value

Tags: scala, error-handling, concurrency, future

Suppose I'm writing a function that receives `Future[A]` and `Future[B]` and returns `Future[(A, Option[B])]` as follows:

```
// return the result of "fa" and then
// either "Some" of the result of "fb" if "fb" has been completed successfully
// or None if "fb" is still not completed or failed
// Note: we check `fb` result after `fa` has completed.

def foo(fa: Future[A], fb: Future[B]): Future[(A, Option[B])] = ???

// foo(Future.successful(a), Future.successful(b)) // Future.successful(a, Some(b))
// foo(Future.successful(a), Future.failed(...))   // Future.successful(a, None)
// foo(Future.successful(a), Future.never)         // Future.successful(a, None)
// foo(Future.failed(...),   Future.successful(b)) // Future.failed(...)
// foo(Future.failed(...),   Future.never)         // Future.failed(...)
```

I am writing `foo` like this:

```
def foo(fa: Future[A], fb: Future[B]): Future[(A, Option[B])] = for {
  a <- fa
  ob <- if (fb.isCompleted) fb.recover { case NonFatal(_) => None } else Future.successful(None)
} yield (a, ob)
```

This implementation seems working. How would you correct or improve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily define `foo` using `value`

```scala
def foo(fa: Future[A], fb: Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[(A, Option[B])] =
  fa.map(a => a -> fb.value.flatMap(_.toOption))
```

This works perfectly because `value` represents exactly what you wanted, the value of the **Future** if it finished or a `None`; Also since the value also captures the possibility of failure as a **Try** and all you want is to transform that in an **Option** you have a pretty one-liner.

As always, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html) is your friend ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution requires an ExecutionContext implicitly in scope. I'd consider `fa.zip(Future.successful(fb.value.flatMap(_.toOption)))` alternatively using `ExecutionContext.parasitic` passed explicitly to `fa.map` since the work to be done is minimal and effect-free.

Comment: @ViktorKlang Thanks. Is `fb.value` invoked after `fa` completion ? I need to wait for `fa` completion and then check if `fb` has completed or not. I guess the `map` solution works this way.

Comment: Ah, so you want the value "at the earliest after fa has been completed"? Then map will be better as zip is eager in its parameter.

Comment: Yes, I want the `value` after `fa` has been completed. I will update the question to make it clear.